# Java app + NTLM proxy

Tags: java, ntlm

What is the simplest way to work with NTLM proxies in Java? Just set `proxyHost/Port/User/Password` seems not work - proxy returns `407 Authentication` required. Anybody have working set of this properties?

Comment: seems java itself with simple HttpUrlConnection works fine with ntlm proxy. In fact i have app, based on metro (JAX-WS RI) and this app show me 407 error when using NTLM proxy. With basic auth on proxy works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved - my app launch as service on windows and in setting user was "current user". And it's not working. Don't know why. When i input my credentials explicitly, 407 error gone.